# Back to a student VS back to become a student?

Tags: meaning

I want to know which one is correct way to describe, I hadn't been studying for a long time. But i am back to school and try to take some course. How do I explain that?

*Thank to Jason reminded, I will demonstrate some example*

sample 1 (without using back)

> I had been working for several years, but I am applying a university right now, I will be a student again soon.

sample 2 (be back)

> I had been working for several years, but I am applying a university right now, I am back to student.

sample 3 (be back to a)

> I had been working for several years, but I am applying a university right now, I am back to a student.

sample 4 (be back to become a)

> I had been working for several years, but I am applying a university right now, I am back to become a student.

sample 5 (be back to studying as a)

> I had been working for several years, but I am applying a university right now, I am back to studying as a student.

Which sentence is more native way to explain that? or you have any other good way to describe that mean?

Comment: Both phrases are grammatical—assuming the right context. (You haven't provided actual sentences.) As to how to express the situation, that's entirely subjective.

Comment: @JasonBassford I have already updated the question, hope you can review it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The verb you want to use in your sentence is 'to be'. You would say

> I am a student.
>   I was a student.

If you were a student before, when you come back you would say

> I am back to being a student.

Your first example is a good way to say it as well, with a few minor corrections.

> I had been working for several years but I am applying to a university right now, so I will be a student again soon.

Your last example works well, too, although the last part, 'as a student' is not really necessary.

> I had been working for several years, but I am applying to a university right now, so I am back to studying as a student.

Answer (score 1):

One could also say:

> I am a student once again.

or

> I am a student once more

in place of

> I am back to being a student.

the verb is still "to be", and I think the form more natural.